# Jquery .click function not working for button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code

```
$('#resetbtnB').click(function() {
$('#bgfade').fadeIn('slow');
$('#webpopup').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This will work if 'resetbtnB' is for example a paragraph or an image. However it does not work when 'resetbtnB' is an input button.

E.g.

Works with

```
<p id="resetbtnB"> Reset </p>
```

Not with

```
<input type="submit" value="Reset" name="resetbtnB" id="resetbtnB"/>
```

Why does this code not work for an input button and how can I change it to work?

Comment: Do both of those elements exist at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because type="submit" also triggers submit event when it is inside form so it is overriding click event.
So either try to remove type "submit" and put "button" write like this

```
<input type="button" value="something" name="resetbtnB" id="resetbtnB"/>
```

Or write jquery function .submit

Docs : https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Demo : https://jsbin.com/morisob/9/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I have added sample demo also, It would be great if it helps you. Thanks

Comment: Adding a `.submit()` handler wouldn't help unless that handler explictly cancels the default submit behaviour. Which could also be done from the `.click()` handler on the `type="submit"` button. (But yes, changing the button to `type="button"` is the best solution if no submission is required.)

Comment: if you are using this button to reset the form - consider giving it a reset type - `<input type="reset" ... />` it will automatically clear all form's inputs

Comment: Yes right ! But what I explained is type submit and click function won't work parallelly. And thanks both @nnnnnn and naortor

Comment: Guyz !! Please up vote if you find this useful so that it will be motivating to help more people  :) Thanks